# [Cobalt]Does cobalt can support the YUVNV12 format?

Tags: cobalt

From the `Cobalt 10.55341`, there defined the `SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12` format in `SbDecodeTargetFormat` in `starboard/decode_target.h`, but after searching through cobalt source code, there is no place to use the SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12, so does cobalt support SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12 at present? If not supported yet, when does it can be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are correct, Cobalt does not yet support rendering SbDecodeTargets with the SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12 format.

That said, we can add support for it.  I've created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38428106 to track this issue, please follow that bug for updates on progress, and also let me know if there is a particularly urgent need to have this support available sooner rather than later, otherwise I'm planning to work on this within a month.

Comment: hi, andrew, we are developing 360 video feaure which is based on SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12 format for better performance, so it's better for cobalt to support SbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12 as earlier as prossible. Thank you so much for your infomration.

Comment: Okay thanks.  This issue is actually fixed now, if you pull the latest Cobalt (either RC_9 or master), NV12 is hooked up to work.